# Add Office 365 API Library to Class Library

Tags: asp.net, api, office365

I realize the documentation doesn't list a Class Library Project as a supported project type but I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction to accomplish using it in one.

My current plan is to start a new web forms app and add it according to the documentation and then start to grab the pieces I need and move them into my library.  Before doing that I wanted to see if someone had a better solution.

Comment: No I didn't.  It seemed like it could be done but you would have to add the dependencies and do all of the work yourself instead of the wizard doing it for you.